# How can I see the daily instace usage on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, dashboard

The app engine dashboard has an Instances view, but it shows the instances in hourly interval. Is there a way to set this interval to day, so I can see the daily sum of instance usage for the last week, for example?

I tried clicking the gray pills, but nothing happens. The arrow on the right reveals the 3 metrics shown, but they cannot be clicked either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To monitor the instance count of my app engine services up to 30 days, I go to [1]. 
There you can filter by service name and time.

[image: Instance dashboard]

[1] https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances

Comment: I run different versions of instances. This allows me to select different versions and see their usage, but I'd like to see a summary. All instance usage per day regardless of version.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/apm) you may find an overview of all the Monitoring tools GCP offers for your Application Performance Management.

Additionally, you can use the [Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer) to display [App Engine Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-appengine), while all versions of your GAE will be concurrently displayed in one chart.

There you may select the metric you would like to display, as for example: "Memory Usage". Furthermore, you can reduce the amount of data returned for a metric by combining data from similar time series, using the ["Group By" and "Aggregator" filtering methods](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector#groupby-option).

I hope this information helps.